# After uploading a file using the browse button in R shiny, the file's name is changed

Tags: r, shiny, rscript, rshiny

I'm having trouble uploading a file in R shiny. What I'm trying to do is, I use the browse button to select the file (file.csv) from folder A and upload it to folder B, but when I see folder B, the file name appears to be "Bfile.csv" after uploading. I'm not sure why the file is being renamed when I upload it.

someone assist me how to solve this issue in R shiny

Below is the code.

```
library(shiny)
library(here)

#path for folder B, where the file to be stored after uploading
file_path<- here('inputfolder/B')

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Select file to upload' )  
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4('List of uploaded files:')
      ,verbatimTextOutput('fileList')
    )
  ))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  observe({  
    if (is.null(input$file1) ) {    return(NULL)  }  
    file.copy(from = input$file1$datapath, to =  paste0(xptpath,input$file1$name )  ) 
  }) 
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You want `file.path`, not `paste0`

Comment: Yes,  It is working well.